# Merge files that have been previously filtered

Tags: git

We have been doing what might be called filtered branch merges.

We merge from an epic working branch into the master branch but using --no-commit and then removing some files from the merge by using `git reset <file>`. That is there are some files that have been changed in the epic that we don't want to merge into master.

Now the time has come to merge these files from the epic branch into master, but those files are not showing up in the merge any longer. These files don't exist in master at all.

How can we merge files that have been removed from previous merges?

---

More info. I expect that the reason for this, is that git is looking at commits. The commits in question appear to have already been merged into the branch, so git skips them.

How can I convince git to reconsider these commits?

Comment: If you truly removed them before committing the merge, then they ceased to exist at the point you committed the merge. Unless you meant you did `git checkout HEAD -- file.dat` or `git reset file.dat` or something instead. But if that's the case, then "removing some files from the merge" makes things a bit unclear...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've edited the question. Indeed, we used `git reset` or similar. The files still exist in the epic branch.

Comment: Have you tried `git cherry-pick`?